# How to perform basic database tasks on MATLAB

Tags: mysql, database, matlab

For my current project I need to perform basic database operations like *Creation, Searching, Insertion, Deletion* etc. The tables I am thinking to use are Excel spreadsheets, since they are required to be editable from outside of my final MATLAB executable by a non-technical end user (simply by opening them through MS-Excel). I have seen options of importing data from an existing database and exporting data to some new database, but not **modifying** the data already present in there, like having multiple tables in a database and executing SQLs like *INSERT INTO TABLE WHERE...* or *DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE...* etc.

Do I at all get to do these operations in MATLAB? Else what is the way?

*I might require to shift to MySQL later*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several choices:

- The (paid) MATLAB Database Toolbox<sup>[1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/index.html)</sup>:

  > Database Toolbox™ provides an app and functions for exchanging data between relational databases and MATLAB®. You can use SQL commands to read and write data or use the Database Explorer app to interact with a database without using SQL.
  >
  > The toolbox supports ODBC-compliant and JDBC-compliant databases, including Oracle®, SAS®, **MySQL®**, Sybase®, Microsoft® SQL Server®, Microsoft Access™, and PostgreSQL.
- Any of the freely-available [fileexchange submissions related to SQL](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?search_submit=fileexchange&query=sql&term=sql) (e.g. [queryMySQL](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28237-querymysql)).
- Solutions using libraries (either directly, or via tools built upon them) written in other languages that are [callable from MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-external-functions.html). Examples of this include the Java-based [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) and the Python-based [MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python).
- Using Octave instead of MATLAB, which has [its own DB tools](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Octave-db).